# IndexedDB - What is Key, keyPath and indexName?

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I am coming from MySQL and I am used to the conventional database table scheme. I am having trouble understanding IndexedDB and some of its terminology. I looked up these definitions in the documentation:

> **Key**
>   A data value by which stored values are organized and retrieved in the object store.
>
> **indexName**
>   The name of the index to create.
>
> **keyPath**
>   The key path for the index to use.

Basically, **Key** is like a *Primary Key* in MySQL, right? Is **indexName** the same thing as a column? And I don't understand what a **keyPath** is.

Can someone explain these for me? Thank you again for you patience :).

Comment: You can read these concepts in detail here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Basic_Concepts_Behind_IndexedDB. Also if you want to wrap the complexities of indexedDb you can use the library https://github.com/sabapk/indexed-db-store

Answer (score 19):

Yes, `key` is like a primary key in SQL.  But others seem to be missing an example explaining the main part of your question, and that is the distinction between `indexName` and `keyPath`.  Per the Mozilla page on [creating an index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/createIndex),

**indexName**
The name of the index to create. Note that it is possible to create an index with an empty name.

**keyPath**
The key path for the index to use. Note that it is possible to create an index with an empty keyPath, and also to pass in a sequence (array) as a keyPath.

The `indexName` is what you use to access that index.  Indexes are used to search that "column" in the database.
The `keyPath` is the actual name of the "column."  See other questions and answers for what forms a `keyPath` may take.
*Note that "column" is not technically correct, but I'm using it because that's what you used.*

For example, suppose your data has the column `hours` and you want to be able to search your database on that column.  When creating your database you would create an index for that column:

```
objectStore.createIndex(indexName, keyPath, { unique: false });
```

where `indexName` can be anything you want, let's say **hoursColumn**, and `keyPath` would be **hours**.

```
objectStore.createIndex("hoursColumn", "hours", { unique: false });
```

`unique: false` just means that other rows of data may have the same value for **hours**.

I can write data to the `objectStore` as follows:

```
db.transaction(storeName, "readwrite").objectStore(storeName).add({hours: 20, minutes: 30});
```

So to search your data on the column **hours**, you could write:

```
var data = db.transaction(storeName).objectStore(storeName).index("hoursColumn").get(20)
```

and the result would be the first row of data where **hours** = 20, e.g. `{hours: 20, minutes: 30}`

So to summarize, **indexName** is just what you call the index you created that you want to search, and **keyPath** is the actual name of the stored data on which you want to search.

Answer (score 7):

Indexes are a way to make it possible to query data in the indexeddb database. As you know objects are stored into the objectstores. These objectstore don't have a schema like you have in an normal SQL database.

An index exists out of 3 important properties:

**indexName**: The indexname is just a name you provide to the index. You will need this name if you want to use the index to query data.

**keyPath**: This defines which property of the object you want to address in your index. For example: you have an object

```
{ foo: "bar" }
```

and you want to query on the foo property, "foo" will be your keypath. The keypath can even go further. You can access nested properties

```
{ foo: { bar: "bla" } }
```

If you want to query the bar property the keypath will be "foo.bar"

**key**: The keys are the values inside the keypath. As you mentioned this key is unique for the index, but this doens't mean this value must be unique over all your objects in the objectstore.

The indexes in the indexeddb work like this:
When you create an index, it creates a new objectstore in which the object will be stored. Instead of storing these object bosed on primary key they are stored based on the values present in the keypath. This means that for a single key in an index you can have multiple objects. So if you start querying an index, it will filter on the keys and return the values that are present in these keys.

Hope this makes indexes clear for you.

Comment: Wow I'm still totally lost.

Answer (score 1):

I am updating my answer here having re-read the topic of Keys and Indexes. Coming from a MySQL background they are indeed confusing with IndexedDB.

(Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Basic_Concepts_Behind_IndexedDB#gloss_outofline_key)

**Indexes**

Typically these occur on elements within your "row" - so for example if you had a row:
`{Hello:"World",Foo:"Bar}` in your database you could set an index (of any name) on say `Hello`. This would be like your indexes in MySQL.

**Keys**

So where Indexes can have multiple, Keys must (as the earlier answer mentions) be unique like MySQL Primary keys. Why this gets confusing is that you can also filter/search your data by Keys as well as Indexes. (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBKeyRange) The difference appears that Key searches appear to be more Ranges (like A-F or > 5 AND < 10) rather than specific values.

There is a very interesting explanation here about keys:

https://golb.hplar.ch/2017/09/A-closer-look-at-IndexedDB.html#primary-keys

Basically it explains that there are 4 types of keys within IndexedDB:

1. `out-of-line` : you provide the key yourself on each insert
2. `out-of-line auto generated` : primary key (i.e. AutoIncrement) number generated automatically
3. `inline` : the contents of field form the index (this is typical to say a MySQL database but *must* then be unique)
4. `inline auto generated`: hidden field (visible in console) added and is accessible through code but not related directly to the object data.

The difference between 2 and 4 is that 2 doesn't get a defined Name, whereas 4 (like a Primary Key in MySQL) does. You could then update (but not insert) on the ID field you've named in 4.

On an aside I believe its called a Keypath because you can call `field.subproperty` which is quite nice. Please also make sure your keys are spelt correctly! Obvious mistake.

Answer (score 1):

It was also hard for me to understand the difference, but at the end I found out and why most of the time we set them the same name.
In short, the `indexName` is how we want to the "field" or "column" (index) will be named in our "table" (Object Store) and the `keyPath` is the property of the stored object that contains the value of the field. Therefore,  is logical that they have the same name.

For example, you have a table with following fields:

- name
- age

They both are the `indexName` of each field, but you have to tell IndexedDB which property (`keyPath`) contains the value of each field.

```
objectStore.createIndex("name", "name", { unique: false });
objectStore.createIndex("age", "age", { unique: false });
```

Answer (score -6):

```
Key       = Row Item
indexName = Column name
keyPath   = Column name
```